# ngFor group by key and display key for each group

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to sort out the best way to get my object grouped and then loop those groups in my template.

The data is not sent to me grouped so in my component, I add a key to each array in the object:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEmailsService.emailsAPI().subscribe(
        data => {
            let firstChar: string
            this.results = data
            this.emails = this.results
            this.emails.forEach(element => {
                firstChar = element.sender_email.charAt(0);
                element.key = firstChar
                console.log(element)
            });
        }
    );
}
```

the resulting dictionary looks like this:

```
created: "2017-10-07T01:42:25.110747Z"
email_domain: "domain.com"
has_user_viewed: false
key: "j"
pk: "wGR"
sender_email:"someone@domain.com"
sender_name: null
```

then in my template I have:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 mb-3" *ngFor="let email of emails | filter : searchText">
```

what would be the best way to handle grouping this by the `key` value and then also displaying the "master" 'key' for each group? so that you had something like:

```
key 
->result
->result
->result 
key 
->result
->result
->result
```

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/groupby.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should keep your Array of objects standard as all the same model in an array without keys. Then if you want to group your array by a specific field this is a handy array transformation that can be passed a field and group the entire array by whatever selector you choose:

```
transformArray(array: Array<any>, field) {
    if (array) {
      const groupedObj = array.reduce((prev, cur) => {
        if (!prev[cur[field]]) {
          prev[cur[field]] = [cur];
        } else {
          prev[cur[field]].push(cur);
        }
        return prev;
      }, {});
      return Object.keys(groupedObj).map(key => ({ key, value: groupedObj[key] }));
    }
    return [];
  }
```

This will group your array into objects with a 'key' of whatever you passed into the method and then a nested array called 'value' which has all the objects related to your grouping field.

Comment: So this can be piped and I have used it as a pipe, but I have been doing research on array transformations in pipes and I have read in various places that array transformations should not be done in a pipe, such as filtering or sorting. I have attached this method to a service that fetches the data for me and then call this method after I have the array of data. In short, either way will work as long as your objects in the array are all the same or at least have one field that is the same.

Comment: I ended up using it as a pipe, but not at the template level, but rather in the component itself so I added the pipe as a provider in the component and then did something like this `this.grouped = this.groupFilterpipe.transform(this.results, 'key')`

Comment: I obviously have some learning to do regarding remapping objects and arrays, as this is over my head, but suggestions on how I could extend this to that the new object is sorted by the key?